# NodeJS + Express 404 on basic routing

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I already created a tutorial Node/Express app earlier and it worked fine, and after trying to copy it and make my new project (ubuntu, then windows), basic routing fails and 404s every time, super frustrating!

I'm trying to reach `/finddrink/margarita` or whatever drink I want.

Here's my app.js with the relevant stuff:

```
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
```

And here is my index.js, in the routes folder:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

/*GET drink recipe*/
router.get('/findrink/:name', function (req,res){
    var db = req.db;
    var drinkName = req.params.name;
    db.collection('recipes').findOne({name: drinkName}, function (err, result) {
        res.send(result);
    });
});
module.exports = router;
```

And lastly, the function trying to access this GET:

```
function loadDrink(drinkToGet) {
  var address = '/finddrink/' + drinkToGet;

  $.getJSON(address, function (item) {
    document.getElementById('drinkTitle').innerHTML = item.name;
  });
};
```

I'm reading the code on my laptop with the running project, then on my desktop with almost identical code, and can't seem to find anything wrong, any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: What is the URL you are trying to reach?

Comment: /finddrink/margarita

Comment: Did you try putting your `/findrink/:name` route in `app.js` instead of `index.js`? Or putting your `/findrink` routes in a separate file and then having `app.use('/findrink', findrinkRoutes);` ?

Comment: Just tried moving the route to app.js, still get a 404. I originally had the route in a separate drink.js file, and tried sticking it into index to solve the problem, so that wasn't it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo:

Your route is setup as findrink in the index.js file:

```
router.get('/findrink/:name', function (req,res){
});
```

But you are asking for finddrink with double d.

You should consider renaming you routes to a more restful approach:

```
router.get('/drinks/:name', function (req,res){
});
```

or

```
router.get('/drinks/find/:name', function (req,res){
});
```

This way you can then extend your API to more routes:

```
// POST /drinks/ creates new drink
router.post('/drinks/', function (req,res){
});

// PUT /drinks/:name edits a drink by na,e
router.put('/drinks/:name', function (req,res){
});

// DELETE /drinks/:name deletes a drink by name
router.delete('/drinks/:name', function (req,res){
});
```

Comment: I'm embarassed I wasted bandwidth for something so silly. I had that design originally, but shifted it for testing. I'll put it back like it was.